# Magento 2 Learning Resources

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I would like to ask, how i can find a full course for magento 2. i want to learn the frontend/backend development.

I have searched for a resource but all what i get is an introduction articles

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [Magento U Training](https://u.magento.com/training/schedule/) might be of use to you.

There are some online 'On Demand' courses that go over some frontend / backend processes.